# Create a new table by deleting some similar rows, provided that their outputs are collected

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

How to delete duplicate rows, collect their outputs in general, and create a new table.

The figure below shows the idea required to create the new table

[image]

The idea is that if the rows are similar in the two columns (L1,L2), the similar ones must be deleted with the sum of the result in (LL) to form a new table, and the values of the column (LL) change as in the above figure.

The data is in the table above:

```
{{L1,L2,LL},{0,0,0},{1,0,1/2},{0,1,0},{1,1,1/2},{1,0,0},{2,0,1},{1,1,1/2},{2,1,1}}
```

I hope the program will be more general when the data increases.

Please Help

Comment: `(new = old //. {s___, {a_, b_, c_}, m___, {a_, b_, d_}, e___} :> {s, {a, b, c + d}, m, e}) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{L1, L2, LL}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1/2},
   {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1/2}, {2, 1, 1}};


data2 = Values @ GroupBy[data, Most, Append[Most@First@#, Total[Last /@ #]] &];

Row[Grid /@ {data, data2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `GatherBy` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
dat = GatherBy[data, Most];
data2 = dat /. x_ /; MatrixQ[x] :> If[Length[x] == 1, x[[1]], {Sequence@@Most@x[[1]], Total[Last/@x]}]

Row[Grid /@ {data, data2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]